# How to make additional 'labels' appear on the columns of an ASP Column Chart?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, html, charts

I have an ASP Column Chart, which takes values from two dropdown menus, "Station" and "Unit" and charts them. This is the code for my chart:

**HomePage.aspx.cs:**

```
void getChartData()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        // Read the data from XML file into DataSet
        ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/MWAvailability2.xml"));
        // Specify the column that contains values for X-AXIS
        ColumnChart.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "AvailDate";
        // Specify the column that contains values for Y-AXIS
        ColumnChart.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "MW";
        // Set DataSet as the DataSource for the Chart control
        ColumnChart.DataSource = ds;
        // Finally call DataBind
        ColumnChart.DataBind();
    }
```

**HomePage.aspx:**

```
<asp:Chart ID="ColumnChart" runat="server" Height="250px" Width="500px">
                <Series>
                    <asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartType="Column" ChartArea="MainArea" IsValueShownAsLabel="true"></asp:Series>
                    <%--<asp:Series Name="Series2" ChartArea="MainArea" Enabled="true" Label='ddStation.SelectedValue' IsValueShownAsLabel="true"></asp:Series>--%>
                </Series>
                <ChartAreas>
                    <asp:ChartArea Name="MainArea" Area3DStyle-Enable3D="false"></asp:ChartArea>
                </ChartAreas>
            </asp:Chart>
```

MainForm.aspx.cs:

```
 void getChartData()
    {
        String ConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cs"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConString))
        {
            String SQLText = "select AvailDate,MW from MWAvailability2 where UnitName = @UnitName and Station = @StationName and AvailDate between @AvailFrom and @AvailTo";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQLText, connection);
            connection.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnitName", ddUnit.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StationName", ddStation.SelectedValue);
            if (TextBoxFrom.Text.Length > 0)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AvailFrom", TextBoxFrom.Text);
                }
            else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AvailFrom", "01-01-1900");
                }
            if (TextBoxTo.Text.Length > 0)
                { 
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AvailTo", TextBoxTo.Text);
                }
            else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AvailTo", "01-01-2050");
                }

            if (TextBoxFrom.Text.Length > 0 && TextBoxTo.Text.Length > 0)   // Text in from, text in to
            {
                chartTitle.Text = "Station " + ddStation.SelectedValue + " " + ddUnit.SelectedValue + " From: " + TextBoxFrom.Text + " To: " + TextBoxTo.Text;
            }
            else if (TextBoxFrom.Text.Length > 0 && TextBoxTo.Text.Length == 0)     // Text in from, no text in to
            {
                chartTitle.Text = "Station " + ddStation.SelectedValue + " " + ddUnit.SelectedValue + " From: " + TextBoxFrom.Text + " To: 01/01/2050";
            }
            else if (TextBoxFrom.Text.Length == 0 && TextBoxTo.Text.Length > 0)     // No text in from, text in to
            {
                chartTitle.Text = "Station " + ddStation.SelectedValue + " " + ddUnit.SelectedValue + " From: 01/01/1900 " + " To: " + TextBoxTo.Text;
            }
            else if (TextBoxFrom.Text.Length == 0 && TextBoxTo.Text.Length == 0)     // No text in from, no text in to
            {
                chartTitle.Text = "Station " + ddStation.SelectedValue + " " + ddUnit.SelectedValue + " From: 01/01/1900 To: 01/01/2050";
            }



            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Series series = ColumnChart.Series["Series1"];
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    series.Points.AddXY(reader["AvailDate"].ToString(), reader["MW"]);

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

**MainForm.aspx:**

```
<asp:Chart ID="ColumnChart" runat="server" Height="250px" Width="500px">
                <Series>
                    <asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartType="Column" ChartArea="MainArea" IsValueShownAsLabel="true"></asp:Series>
                    <%--<asp:Series Name="Series2" ChartArea="MainArea" Enabled="true" Label='ddStation.SelectedValue' IsValueShownAsLabel="true"></asp:Series>--%>
                </Series>
                <ChartAreas>
                    <asp:ChartArea Name="MainArea" Area3DStyle-Enable3D="false"></asp:ChartArea>

                </ChartAreas>
            </asp:Chart>
```

**This is what my chart currently looks like:**
[image]

**And this is what the feature I am trying to add might look like:**
[image]

I have looked all over the Visual Studio documentation, this website, Google, even Google Images, but it seems no one, at least as far as I can tell, has done something like this. I have also tried all of the functionality from ColumnChart.Series, but nothing here suits my needs.

Most column charts I have seen just have the X and Y axis labels and a label in or on top of the columns, but I need a fourth element that can coexist IN each of the columns, which in this case comes from the value of the "Station" dropdown, but could also come from "Unit".

I understand what I'm asking is probably confusing or maybe there is something obvious that I am overlooking, but I could really use some help here.

I am more than willing to provide any additional information that is needed, anybody that could help me out or at least point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I had briefly looked at that... would I use the line annotations? And would this achieve the desired effect?

Comment: Looking into it more maybe box annotations would work better? I'm not sure. Either way how would I go about implementing them?